# ExpandableListView with Headers always visible

Tags: android, listview, user-interface, adapter, expandablelistview

I want to create a ExpandableListView like shown in the image[image]

Gradovi, Brands and Kategorije should always be visible, so, it doesnt matter how many child items are there or if they are expanded or not, I want them parents be visible always. Is there a library or some sample that I can use to do this?

Comment: have you tried something?

Comment: tried creating my custom view with dynamic listviews, not working, don't know what constraints should there be for the view to allways be at the bottom, but, simultainously how to implement animations for expanding and collapsing lists when the headers are at the bottom.